# I got exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

> var mToolbar= FindViewById (Resource.Id.toolbar);Exception has been
>   thrown by the target of an invocation

```html
DrawerLayout  drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //ActionBar.NavigationMode = ActionBarNavigationMode.Tabs;
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        var mToolbar= FindViewById<Toolbar> (Resource.Id.toolbar);
        //Toolbar will now take on default action bar chacracteritics
        SetActionBar(mToolbar);
        ActionBar.Title = "home";




        //Enable suppport action bar to display hamburger
        ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.icon_hambuger);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        //Set menu hambuger
        ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator (Resource.Drawable.icon_home);
        ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);

        drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout> (Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView> (Resource.Id.nav_view);

        navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
            e.MenuItem.SetChecked (true);
            //react to click here and swap fragments or navigate
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers ();
        };




        // Add tabs to tabbar



        //AddTab ("Genres", new GenerFragment ());
        //AddTab ("Explore", new ExploreFragment ());
        //AddTab ("Audio", new AudioFragment ());

    }


    //Event Selected on nav menu
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected (IMenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.ItemId) 
        {
        case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
            drawerLayout.OpenDrawer (Android.Support.V4.View.GravityCompat.Start);
            return true;
        }
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected (item);
    }

    // Add options menu on toolbar

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.Action_menu, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
    }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Xamarin.android has more issues so far. I don't know where is errors. I fixed old errors and then showing new errors.@@
. How to solve it. Thanks.

```html
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidProgramException: Missing or incorrect header for method .ctor
at at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:644
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:650
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00089] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:635
at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:663
at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/ConstructorInfo.cs:62
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:303
at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x0012c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:277
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x000e5] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:371
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:342
at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Lang/Object.cs:334
at Android.App.Activity.FindViewById (Int32 id) [0x00077] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1939
at Android.App.Activity.FindViewById[T] (Int32 id) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Android.App/Activity.cs:12
at SoundCloud.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x00019] in /Users/hoanglethien/Desktop/SoundCloud/SoundCloud/MainActivity.cs:29
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-23/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2857
at at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:d02a4f71-fdeb-4fc8-8465-eedc540c9cd9 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace of this exception?

Comment: Updated more information

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the Support Design library for backwards-compatibility. Try wrapping your toolbar in an AppBarLayout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```